# How to make base path available in views 3 Drupal 7?

Tags: views

Without use of [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php%20module) module, I need to use `base_path` for a link. Although using views_php module, we can add it inside php code but is there any way without using this module OR we'll have to write code to create something like handler.
Currently available fields in my module are following:

```
 Content: Add comment link
Display the standard add comment link used on regular nodes, which will only display if the viewing user has access to add a comment.
 Content: All taxonomy terms
Display all taxonomy terms associated with a node from specified vocabularies.
 Content: Author uid
The user authoring the content. If you need more fields than the uid add the content: author relationship
 Content: Body
Appears in: node:page, node:article, node:event_calendar.
 Content: Comment count
The number of comments a node has.
 Content: Comment status
Whether comments are enabled or disabled on the node.
 Content: Delete link
Provide a simple link to delete the content.
 Content: Edit link
Provide a simple link to edit the content.
 Content: Event Date
Appears in: node:event_calendar.
 Content: Event Status
Appears in: node:event_calendar.
 Content: Has new content
Show a marker if the content is new or updated.
 Content: Image
Appears in: node:article.
 Content: Last comment author
The name of the author of the last posted comment.
 Content: Last comment time
Date and time of when the last comment was posted.
 Content: Last comment uid
The User ID of the author of the last comment of a node.
 Content: Link
Provide a simple link to the content.
 Content: New comments
The number of new comments on the node.
 Content: Nid
The node ID.
 Content: Path
The aliased path to this content.
 Content: Post date
The date the content was posted.
 Content: Promoted to front page
Whether or not the content is promoted to the front page.
 Content: Published
Whether or not the content is published.
 Content: Sticky
Whether or not the content is sticky.
 Content: Title
The content title.
 Content: Type
The content type (for example, "blog entry", "forum post", "story", etc).
 Content: Updated date
The date the content was last updated.
 Content: Updated/commented date
The most recent of last comment posted or node updated time.
 Content revision: Delete link
Provide a simple link to delete the content revision.
 Content revision: Link
Provide a simple link to the revision.
 Content revision: Log message
The log message entered when the revision was created.
 Content revision: Revert link
Provide a simple link to revert to the revision.
 Content revision: Title
The content title.
 Content revision: Updated date
The date the node was last updated.
 Content revision: Vid
The revision ID of the content revision.
 File Usage: Entity ID
The ID of the entity that is related to the file.
 File Usage: Entity type
The type of entity that is related to the file.
 File Usage: Module
The module managing this file relationship.
 File Usage: Use count
The number of times the file is used by this entity.
 FullCalendar: Google Calendar
Display events from a Google Calendar.
 Global: Contextual Links
Display fields in a contextual links menu.
 Global: Custom text
Provide custom text or link.
 Global: Math expression
Evaluates a mathematical expression and displays it.
 Global: View result counter
Displays the actual position of the view result
 Scheduler: Publish countdown
Time until the article will be automatically published
 Scheduler: Publish on
Date/time on which the article will be automatically published
 Scheduler: Unpublish countdown
Time until the article will be automatically unpublished
 Scheduler: Unpublish on
Date/time on which the article will be automatically unpublished
 Search: Score
The score of the search item. This will not be used if the search filter is not also present.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is something in the view core.
If youre planning to output some field with base path, follow the steps to get an absolute path.

1. Click on the Field
2. Scroll down to **REWRITE RESULTS**
3. Check **Output this field as a link** checkbox
4. Check **Use absolute path** checkbox

[image]

*If you're looking this for just a link [Views PHP](http://drupal.org/project/views_php) is a good choice.*

If youre not happy with this method take a look at [How to create a custom Views handler](http://tanc.me/blog/2011/how-create-custom-views-handler)